# Use Jquery tmpl(or underscore) with a simple array?

Tags: jquery

Right now I have a simple template which of course takes an object:

```
    <div class="pic"><span class="handle"></span> <h3>${sn}</h3>

    <h4>${ag}</h4>
    <img src = "imagepull/images/${sn}.jpg" />
    </div>

 </script>
```

Suppose I wanted to simply pass an array like:

var data= ['tom',30,'tompic.gif'];

Could you do that with a template? My goal is to pull a numeric column array off PDO, json_encode,  and avoid sending useless repeating long field names.

Comment: Can you use {{each}} to iterate over the array?

Comment: I guess I can "objectify" it on the client using each. Good thinking!

Comment: I posted an answer so this isn't left 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{each}}` to iterate over the array